# Add a custom html to leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I have a html template. I want to add on map the template to left position. Firstly I added map containter. Here the problem is when zoom is changed the custom template is disappearing. How can I use different way?

**HTML**

```
    <div id="map" class="active"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><button onclick="fullSc();"><span>Full sc</span></button></li>
        <li><button onclick="findMe();"><span>Find</span></button></li>        
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
  var map = L.map('map', {
       zoomControl: true,
       maxZoom: 18,
       minZoom: 0
  }).setView([41.00650212603, 28.8530806151128], 13);

 L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
 }).addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter(), {
    draggable: true,
    icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: '/assets/img/pin-4ldpi.png',
        iconSize: [30, 35],
        iconAnchor: [30 / 2, 35],
    })
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Could you share the css for the ul? Or even better a jsbin demo.

Comment: I used Bootstrap framework. I'm new on Leaflet. Should I create a custom css?

Comment: It seems that your ui problem has nothing to do with leaflet. If your ul is positionned absolutely, try to set a z-index high enough so that it stays on top.

Comment: When map width is changed the template won't work correctly. I want to embed on map. For example zoom control. How can I do?

Comment: i’m sorry, I don’t understand what you want. May a demo somewhere you can reproduce the problem would help us help you.
Zoom control is a config within leaflet, you dont need to add it yourself.